# Get DataContractSerializer to work without fixed ordering

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

Is there a way I can get Data Contract Serializer to work where properties are not always ordered.

I cannot use XML Serializer, as i use WCF and my app sits on a framework which conflicts with xmlserializer.

Comment: Why can't you set the ordering?  Sounds like a more sensible plan.

Comment: I cant, It would break the earlier configs

Comment: (removed previous suggestion) hmmm; it looks like DCS is really *really* fussy about order... even for a group of properties with the same `Order=`, it wants them in a set layout (presumably alphabetical).

Comment: Does it have to be DCS?  It sounds like you might need to roll your own.